# Scss dynamically select an element

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, less

I want to know if is there a way to select dynamically an element with same prefix of class but different suffix. Ex:

```
HTML
<div class="bg-primary-light"></div>
<div class="bg-primary-dark"></div>
CSS 
.bg-primary-light { background-color: #fff }
.bg-primary-dark { background-color: #000 }
```

Is there a way to select for example

```
.bg-primary {
      height: 100px;
      .-light { background-color: #fff; }
      .-dark {background-color: #000 } 
}
```

`

Just to keep the "parent" properties

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute selector with the `*=` operator to select elements by its partial class name

```css
[class*="bg-primary"][class*="-light"] { background-color: #fff; }
[class*="bg-primary"][class*="-dark"] { background-color: #000; }
```

Comment: so, should i rewrite the "bg-primary" class?

Comment: You can place this outside the `.bg-primary` selector, otherwise the CSS selector produced by sass will be `.bg-primary [class*="bg-primary"][class*="-light"]`